# Using Kubernetes-client/go gives a Azure compiler error

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes

Kubernetes-client/go - trying [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/go/blob/master/examples/create-pod/main.go) example

Note: I am using go.mod file

Do you know why I get this Azure error?

```
 go run .
# github.com/kubernetes-client/go/kubernetes/config
../../gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/kubernetes-client/go@v0.0.0-20190402190921-ee48eb4f6eed/kubernetes/config/azure.go:63:3: cannot use l.user.AuthProvider.Config["expires-in"] (type string) as type json.Number in field value
../../gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/kubernetes-client/go@v0.0.0-20190402190921-ee48eb4f6eed/kubernetes/config/azure.go:64:3: cannot use l.user.AuthProvider.Config["expires-in"] (type string) as type json.Number in field value
```